# How to use css3 translate to move to an absolute position

Tags: javascript, css

How would I use css3 to translate to an absolute position. It seems that it always translates relative to my current location (where my current location is 0,0), but I'd rather it translate it relative to the screen, so that the upper left portion of the screen is 0,0.

http://jsbin.com/qujabe/1/edit

For example, I'd like to be able to move the red box (when clicked) onto the green box using the green box's offset() position. (note: I want to do this with css3 translate not left/top absolute coordinates)

Comment: Wrap the boxes with a container div and get the position of your box in relation to the container div. Then subtract that value from the position within the container and add the destination you want your box to go to. I.e. if your box's position is 100px from left and 100px from top, (get the distances) and subtract from your position and add destination: 100-100+30 + "px". As of right now you're adding the 30 to your existing 100, which means the box is positioning itself relative to itself

Comment: `If the property has a value different than none, a stacking context will be created. In that case the object will act as a containing block for position: fixed elements that it contains.` Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#summary

Comment: ctwheels, not a bad solution thanks. altho instead of putting the boxes in the container just take the offset() of each box

Answer (score 1):

Here, add this before your function "flyToBox2()"

```
var myVarW = $("#box1").offset().left;
var myVarH = $("#box1").offset().top;
```

and change

```
translate('#box1',30,30, '1s');
```

to

```
translate('#box1',-myVarW+30,-myVarH+30, '1s');
```

Unfortunately jsfiddle is down at the moment, otherwise I would include a link to a fiddle as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up doing it.

```
function translateToAbsolute(sel, x, y, dur)
{
    var offset = $(sel).offset();

    var newX = -offset.left+x;
    var newY = -offset.top+y;

    $(sel).css('transition','all '+dur+' ease');
    $(sel).css('transform','translate('+newX+'px,'+newY+'px)');
}
```